# Managing Files inside multipart/form-data API Gateway Request Body

Tags: aws-lambda, multipartform-data, java-11, serverless-application-model

I'm using AWS SAM to deploy locally my Lambda function and test it.

I'm creating a function that receives a `multipart/form-data` body (includes a pdf file). When I do the request, lambda returns a `502 BAD GATEWAY` message, but if I send only the text attributes or text files (markdown, text, xml, html) instead of binary files (pdf, images, etc.) It works. Here's my code.

**template.yml**

```yaml
...
  PostRequest:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
      Handler: com.demo.handlers.request.PostRequest
      Runtime: java11
      Description: Post a Request
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 100
      Events:
        HttpPost:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /requests
            Method: post
            BinaryMediaTypes:
              - "multipart/form-data"
...
```

I tried adding `application/pdf` to the `BinaryMediaTypes` property but It still not working.

Is there a workaround to manage this?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late, but I'm dropping what works for me in case someone land here and have the same issue.

```yaml
...

Globals:
  Api:
    BinaryMediaTypes:
      - "*~1*"
Resources:
  PostRequest:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      Properties:

...
```

Comment: Wow, hours and hours trying to figure out this.

Using SAM to test locally I was seen this error:
```UnicodeDecodeError while processing HTTP request: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 194: invalid continuation byte```

After reading a lot, this was the only thing that fixed.
Thank you.